# How to append a numpy Array into another one

Tags: python, numpy

This is my code...

```
image_paths = dt_labels['image']
train_X = np.ndarray([])
for image_path in image_paths:
    path = './Dataset/' + image_path
    img = cv2.imread(path, 0)
    vectorized_img = img.reshape(img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], 1)
    train_X = np.append(train_X, vectorized_img, axis=1)
```

As you can see, i have an ndarray in the var named train_X, and... i read an image and reshape it into a vector of one dimention, and when i try to append into the ndarray train_X, and i got this error:

> zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated

I just want to concatenate the multiple arrays "vectorized_img" into the train_X ndarray in horizontal

Comment: Collect the arraysin a list and do one `concatenate`.  Read its docs and pay attention to dimensions.  If you insist on using `np.append` follow the rules for matching dimensions.  Don't guess `train_X.shape`; verify!

Comment: did you actually read the docs for `np.ndarray`?  It's not the same as the more commonly used `np.array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [103]: train_X = np.ndarray([])
     ...: print(train_X.shape)
     ...: for i in range(3):
     ...:     vectorized_img = np.ones((4, 1))
     ...:     train_X = np.append(train_X, vectorized_img, axis=1)
     ...: 
()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-103-26d2205beb4e>", line 5, in <module>
    train_X = np.append(train_X, vectorized_img, axis=1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in append
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4745, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

`np.append` just calls `np.concatenate`.  One argument has shape (), the other (4,1).  The error is that it can't join those.

`np.ndarray([])` is NOT a clone of `[]`, and `np.append` is not a clone of list `append`.   `concatenate` says that the number of dimensions must match, and the size of the dimensions must also match (except for the concatenate one).

To join 'columns' we need to start with a 'column'

```
In [111]: train_X = np.ones((4,0))
     ...: for i in range(3):
     ...:     vectorized_img = np.ones((4, 1))
     ...:     train_X = np.append(train_X, vectorized_img, axis=1)
     ...: train_X.shape
Out[111]: (4, 3)
```

Or we could start with (0,1) and join on `axis=0`.

But it's faster, and less prone to errors it we stick with list append:

```
In [114]: alist = []
     ...: for i in range(3):
     ...:     vectorized_img = np.ones((4, 1))
     ...:     alist.append(vectorized_img)
     ...: np.concatenate(alist, axis=1)
Out[114]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```